# How to save changes in a BackTrack virtual machine?

Tags: virtual-machine, backtrack

Is there any way to save changes in a BackTrack virtual machine using VirtualBox?
I've tried every way, but on every next boot the settings
(changes like changing the background wallpaper or such) revert to the default.

Answer (score 0):

Install backtrack to the VM - don't just use the Live CD option when starting.